# How to retrieve multiple table's data with Yes/No Abbreviation

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 5 Tables

```
Village
```

[image]

```
 T1_Master (Village_ID is a foreign key)
```

[image]

```
T2_Master (Village_ID is a foreign key)
```

[image]

`T1_Details (t1_id is a foreign key) & (month,year,t1_id are combination of primary key` (composite key))

[image]

`T2_Details (t2_id is a foreign key) & (month,year,t2_id are combination of primary key` (composite key))
[image]

Now if I want to retrieve the records where `village_ID = 01, month=03 and year=2013`

then output should be like following

[image]

```
here t1_1(No) = t1_1 has no record for month=03 and year=2013
```

`Like wise t2_1(Yes) = t2_1 has record for month=03 and year=2013` and so on...

Plz help me....plz

Comment: Please show your attempt at writing the query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to impliment one ore more LEFT or RIGHT JOIN (s):

```
 SELECT
    V.Village_ID    
    , Dates.[MONTH]
    , Dates.[YEAR]
    , CASE WHEN colValue IS NULL THEN 'no'
         ELSE 'yes'
         END [Yes or No]
FROM
    (
    SELECT
       Village_ID
    FROM 
        Villages
    WHERE
        Village_ID = @ParamVilageID
    ) V
    LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        Viilage_ID
        , [MONTH]
        , [YEAR]
    FROM
        T1_Details
    WHERE
        [MONTH] = @ParamMonth
        AND
        [YEAR] = @ParamYear
    ) Dates
    ON V.Village_ID = Dates.Village_ID
```

Youl need to decide which column you're referencing as colValue but all the SQL elements are there. SQL will infer the data type (string) from tha case statment, but you can return a straight boolean 0 or 1 as well

BTW it would be much better to had a single smallDate column because SQL has DatePart and DateName  Functions

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use outer joins to get the null values (you may want to consider finding some available tutorials on left joins - many out there on google).  The key is to use the master tables to display the id's when the details rows aren't available.

```
SELECT  v.Village_id, 
        CASE WHEN t1d.t1_id IS NULL THEN CAST(t1m.t1_id AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' (No)'
                ELSE CAST(t1m.t1_id AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' (Yes)'
        END T1,
        CASE WHEN t2d.t2_id IS NULL THEN CAST(t2m.t2_id AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' (No)'
                ELSE CAST(t2m.t2_id AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' (Yes)'
        END T2
FROM Village v 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN T1_Master t1m
        ON t1m.Village_ID = v.Village_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN T1_Details t1d
        ON t1d.t1_id = t1m.t1_id
            AND t1d.[month] = 03
            AND t1d.[year] = 2013
        LEFT OUTER JOIN T2_Master t2m
        ON t2m.Village_ID = v.Village_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN T2_Details t2d
        ON t2d.t2_id = t2m.t2_id
            AND t2d.[month] = 03
            AND t2d.[year] = 2013
WHERE v.Village_ID = 01
```

Depending on your nulls settings on the database, the `CAST(t2m.t2_id AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' (No)'` statement may need to check to see if the t2m record is null to get it to display null instead of just '(No)'